# Three20 linker error

Tags: iphone, object, linker, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have the following line of code:

```
if( !self.isLoading && TTIsEmptyString !TTIsEmptyString(_username) )
```

and it results in the following error:

Undefined symbols:
  "_TTIsEmptyString", referenced from:
      -[UserModel load:more:] in UserModel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I've read, that linker errors come from 'not included' libraries, but the three20 lib is included in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest version of Three20 removed this method without really making as big of a news flash about it as it should have. It took me a while to troubleshoot this, but basically you just need to change all calls to TTIsEmptyString to TTIsSetWithItems, for example:

```
if( !self.isLoading && !TTIsSetWithItems(_username) )
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed to fix an error run into in this tutorial: http://Three20.info/tutorials/github/page/3